# how to troubleshoot remotely if sever crashs/ hangs/ blue screen

Tags: remote-access

how to troubleshoot remotely if sever crashs/ hangs/ blue screen.

Comment: Want to actually give us some details? It's kinda pointless to post such a broad question.

Answer (score 5):

You need an out-of-band management system. Most commercial servers have a facility for this; for example, HP servers are equipped with [Systems Insight Manager](http://h18013.www1.hp.com/products/servers/management/hpsim/index.html). If you're working on a computer that doesn't have something like this built-in, you will need an [IP KVM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KVM_switch#Remote_KVM_devices) and a network attached PDU.

Answer (score 1):

1. Get in car
2. Drive to data center
3. Look at server monitor screen

Answer (score 0):

It might have helped if you'd mentioned what OS this relates to.

Since you refer to 'blue screen' I assume you mean Microsoft Windows. Unfortunately MS Windows has never been very good for remote access, nor for diagnostics/post-mortem analysis.

Any good UPS should provide remote access to power cycle the server.

Answer (score 0):

Also you could use netconsole (on linux) which allow a remote syslog daemon to record console output from your system.